# Fail to call DoModal Twice in a Dialog-based VC++ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am a beginner in VC++ programming and I have a problem when I was developing a dialog-based VC++ application (VS2010+WIN7). Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

I created two dialog classes, CTestDialog and CMyDialog. CTestDialog is the dialog shown when the application runs. When its "OK" button is clicked, I want to show the other dialog, i.e. CMyDialog twice. Below is the code:

```
void CTestDialog::OnBnClickedOk()

{

CDialog::OnOK(); 

CMyDialog dlg1;

dlg1.DoModal();

MessageBox("Show me again!");

CMyDialog dlg2;

dlg2.DoModal();

}
```

The first dialog dlg1 shows correctly, but the second one dlg2 doesn't work. VS told me

> "Debug Assertion Failed!
>   File:f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wingdi.cpp Line:1119"

Can anyone solve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you `#include "CMyDialog.h"` ?

Comment: If you look at the code where the assertion was generated, it should give you a hint.

Comment: probably you are creating/destroying some window handles in `CMyDialog` and not cleaning up right. Try putting each set in brackets {`CMyDlg x; x.DoModal();}` or show us what's in `CMyDialog`

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score -1):

For the Windows Application, you can't pop up two modal dialog at same time, that's why you got the assert for the second DoModal.

Comment: You can do it fine as long as the second one is a child of the first.

Comment: Thank you Matt and @MarkRansom so much for your comments. My program is for a psychological experiment. People will see a picture and make a choice and see another picture, make a choice and so on. That's why I want to show CMyDialog twice (or more than twice). I just want CMyDialog to be a interface to show a different picture for each time when people click the "OK" button. I can create dialogs for showing each picture, but that's a too clumsy way. If you know any ways to realize this, that will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi everyone, I just replaced the dialog-based application with a Single Document based application and the problem is gone. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.